# Cache by Unique Id in Angular

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs

I want to implement caching in Angular. I have two methods GetAll() and GetById(id: number as below.

For GetAll(), I implemented Cache and it is working fine. Here is the implementation

```
private cache$: Observable<any>;
getAll() {
  if (!this.cache$) {
     this.cache$ = this.getAll().pipe(
     shareReplay(1)
   );
 }
 return this.cache$; 
}
```

Now, I want to implement based on cache and I have many Id's. How can I cache based on the Id.

```
getById(id: number) {
if (!this.cache$) {
  this.cache$ = this.getById(id).pipe(
    shareReplay(1)
  );
}
return this.cache$;
```

}

Obviously, I don't want to create cache$ based on Id upfront.

How can I do it in angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary to keep all cached observables by id:

```
cacheMap = {}

getById(id: number) {
  if (!this.cacheMap[id]) {
    this.cacheMap[id] = ...
  }

  return this.cacheMap[id];
}
```